# Stop Select Case from repeating in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm sorry the title was vague, I didn't know how to explain this problem concisely.

I have this bit of code, here:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Left
                pBox1.Visible = False
                pBox3.Visible = False
                pBox2.Visible = True
                Me.pBox1.Left -= 3
                Me.pBox2.Left -= 3
                Me.pBox3.Left -= 3
                Me.pBox4.Left -= 3
            Case Keys.Right
                pBox1.Visible = False
                pBox3.Visible = False
                pBox2.Visible = True
                Me.pBox1.Left += 3
                Me.pBox2.Left += 3
                Me.pBox3.Left += 3
                Me.pBox4.Left += 3
            Case Keys.E
                pBox2.Visible = False
                pBox3.Visible = False
                pBox1.Visible = True
            Case Keys.Up
                pBox4.Visible = True
                pBox3.Visible = False
                pBox2.Visible = False
                pBox1.Visible = False
                Me.pBox4.Top -= 3
                Me.pBox3.Top -= 3
                Me.pBox2.Top -= 3
                Me.pBox1.Top -= 3


        End Select
    End Sub
```

This works fine, the different pBoxes represent the different picture boxes I want to move. Everything works, the picture boxes move left/right/up, but I want to stop the 'up' one from repeating (I am making a video game character move to the left/right/jump) so the player can't just float into the air. I want the 'Case Keys.Up' to only repeat once, so it works like a proper jumping mechanic, or something like that. Does anyone know how to do this? Any answers are appreciated, thanks in advance!

-Aaron

Comment: This question has got nothing to do with `Select Case`.  The question is how to detect how many times the `KeyDown` event has been raised for the `Up` key.  How is what you do when that key is detected relevant?  An important part of finding the information you need to determining what information you need and if you include irrelevant parameters then you make it harder to find relevant information.

Comment: So, what actually matters to you?  That the `KeyUp` event has been raised since the last `KeyDown` event?  If so then it should be obvious that you at least need to handle the `KeyUp` event.  Now consider the logic required to determined what you need to determine.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't know it wasn't Select Case. But I think you misread my question. What I want is for the player to press the up arrow, and have the character on screen move up, then down. All it does now is if the player holds down the up arrow, the character just starts floating into the air. It has nothing to do with the key down event

Comment: Sorry if I am totally being stupid, I am almost completely knew to vb and stack overflow. Sorry!

Comment: You might want to look at the `KeyPress` event in combination with or instead of the `KeyDown` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more complicated than you might think. The thing is, you don't need a snippet of code. You need a new way to look at your code.

What you want is a design pattern named "States".

[Here's a link](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html), just for you.

Just to help you start, here's some pointers. Your character can do many things. You can divide those things in states. Maybe your character can stay idle, walk, run, jump, fall and die. All of these are states, and by enforcing those states you kinda have a mask that will "change the rules" your character abides for any of these instances. For an example, your character may have different animations for every one of these states. It's max speed might be different for these, too. Maybe he becomes vulnerable or invincible in some situations.

By enforcing states, you create a strict structure around your character's behavior, which is both easier to custom and harder to make exceptions to. Most games use this pattern a lot.

Good programming!

Comment: Thanks Laancelot! That helped a lot!

Comment: I just want to add something: if you're serious in making a game, states often are the way to go. On the other hand, if this is a ninja-coded homework, you can use a boolean to know if you're currently jumping or not and avoid complicating your code further. Good luck!